# Converting items inside ArrayList to different types

Tags: java, arraylist, simpledateformat

I have a part inside my program where the user logs into have access to the application, when the user logs in I have a time stamp being taken and stored into an ArrayList. When the user logs out I have another time stamp taken for when they logged out. I have been trying to subtract the 2 times from each other, but it is not allowing me to. They are stored in a String ArrayList, I am aware you can't subtract String, so I have tried converting to double, int, date, etc... None of it works for me. My question is that I would like the difference between the two times. I am also aware that there are other question similar to this on SO, but none specific to this exact question, that is why I posted it. I am not trying to post a duplicate.

Code:

```
 loginButton.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener()
        {
           //method for events that will be performed when 'loginButton' is pressed
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {                   
              try
              {                   
                 //gets texts from specified text fields and assigns to instance variable
                 String userNameFromLogin = userNameTextBox.getText().trim();
                 String password = passwordTextBox.getText().trim();

                 //instance variable and object that holds currrent time when logged in                    
                 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm");
                 Date date = new Date();
                 String loginTime = dateFormat.format(date);

                 //sql statement that check if username and password exist
                 String sql5 = "SELECT User_name,Password FROM Employee_Table WHERE User_name = '" + userNameFromLogin + "' and Password = '" + password + "'";

                 //execute query, assigning all records in db to 'rs5'
                 rs5 = st.executeQuery(sql5);

                 //instance variables
                 int count = 0;

                 //loops until reaches end up 'rs5'
                 while(rs5.next())
                 {
                    count++;
                 }

                 //statement and actions if 'userName' and 'password' match
                 if(count == 1)
                 { 
                    //sets 'welcomeFrame' to true                    
                    welcomeFrame.setVisible(true);

                    //sets 'loginFrame' to false
                    loginFrame.setVisible(false);

                    //sets text fields to blank
                    userNameTextBox.setText("");
                    passwordTextBox.setText("");

                    //adds 'userNameFromLogin' to array
                    loginArray.add(userNameFromLogin);

                    //adds 'loginTime' to array
                    loginArray.add(loginTime);

                    //sets label to current username logged in                       
                    userNameLabel.setText("logged in as: " + userNameFromLogin);   
                 }

                 //statement and actions if 'userName' and 'password' do not match 
                 else
                 {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or password incorrect!");
                    userNameTextBox.setText("");
                    passwordTextBox.setText("");
                 }   
              }

              catch(Exception ex)
              {

              }               
           }
        });
}

logoutHomeButton.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener()
        {
           //method for events that will be performed when 'employeeFormButton' is pressed
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
              try
              {
                 //instance variable and object that holds currrent time when logged in                    
                 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm");
                 Date date = new Date();
                 String logoutTime = dateFormat.format(date);

                 //sets 'loginFrame' to visible
                 loginFrame.setVisible(true);

                 //sets 'welcomeFrame' to not visible
                 welcomeFrame.setVisible(false); 

                 //adds 'logoutTime' to array
                 loginArray.add(logoutTime);

                 //statement that selects everything from our 'Login_Info'
                 String sql7 = "SELECT * FROM Login_Info";

                 //execute query, assigning all records in db to 'rs7'
                 rs7 = st.executeQuery(sql7);                 

                 //moves cursor to next row                                           
                 rs7.moveToInsertRow();

                 //inserts record into db                                     
                 rs7.updateString("User_Name", loginArray.get(0));
                 rs7.updateString("Login_Time", loginArray.get(1));
                 rs7.updateString("Logout_Time", loginArray.get(2));

                 //inserts data into db      
                 rs7.insertRow();               

                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have successfully logged out!");
              }

              catch(Exception ex)
              {

              }
           }
        });
}
```

The ArrayList is a global variable at the top of my program. The two variable names I will be subtracting are **loginTime** and **logoutTime** and their respected indexes inside the ArrayList.

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: You have a design problem: You should not store *`Strings`* in your list of log in/out timestamps. You should store `Date` objects, which are essentially timestamps. Then you can subtract the times of each date pair.

Comment: @javaGeek Way too much code shown. It's your job to pull out the relevant parts of the code in question, not ours. You are asking about an ArrayList of date-time values. So we do not need queries for passwords in a database nor JOptionPane. Also, you say your question is different (not a duplicate) but you neglect to explain what makes it special. Seems like the oft-repeated questions of (a) How to query database for date-time values, (b) How to parse strings into date-time values, and (c) How to calculate elapsed time.

Comment: @BasilBourque No, C is the only question I had, if you read, I have already parsed to those types and never mentioned how to query my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the strings back to dates using your `SimpleDateFormat.parse()`. Once they are both in `Date` format:

```
long elapsed = logoutDate.getTime() - loginDate.getTime();  // Elapsed time in ms
```